# update-grub on Debian 11 fails

Tags: debian, grub

I am trying to update the GRUB config on a Debian 11 VM. I was using the `update-grub` command, but this doesn't seem to work anymore. I also tried `grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg` command, which also failed.

Both commands fail with this error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 38: /etc/default/grub.d/grub.cfg: function: not found
```

The `grub.cfg` file is in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

When I review `grub-mkconfig` on line 38, it shows these lines:

```shell
grub_mkconfig_dir="${sysconfdir}"/grub.d
```

The sysconf dir is `/etc/`.

I've checked out the man pages, which indicate that `grub-mkconfig` should work.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's only a dummy file `init-select.cfg` containing a few comments in my `/etc/default/grub.d/` directory, that's all (Debian 11).

There shouldn't be a `grub.cfg` in this directory. Could it be you ran `grub-mkconfig -o /etc/default/grub.d/grub.cfg` by mistake?

If you remove the file, `sudo update-grub` should work again.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve this problem is reinstalling grub.

Attach the Debian iso file to your VM then boot. Once done chroot into the broken system then reinstall grub.

Here is how to change root and reinstalling grub:
(Replace `sdaXY` with your root partition.)

```
mkdir -p /tmp/mychroot
mount -t ext4 /dev/sdaXY /tmp/mychroot
mount --bind /proc /tmp/mychroot/proc
mount --bind /dev /tmp/mychroot/dev
mount --bind /sys /tmp/mychroot/sys
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sdX
exit
```

Unmount the mounted partitions, then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Your file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is corrupted. In line 38 of this file, there should be text like:

```
38  function savedefault {
40    if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
41      saved_entry="${chosen}"
42      save_env saved_entry
43    fi
44  }
```

[From this answer at the Ubuntu exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192919/usr-sbin-grub-mkconfig-1-etc-default-grub-if-not-found), I understand the error

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 38: /etc/default/grub.d/grub.cfg: function: not found
```

is telling you that `grub-mkconfig` **did not find** a **function in line 38 of file `/etc/default/grub.d/grub.cfg`**

I spun a virtual Debian 11x64machine, and copied the `/etc/default/grub.d/grub.cfg`. You can compare your existing file with [this copy](https://github.com/cybertrapped/stackexchange/blob/main/grub.cfg).